# strange behavior with git rename that only changed case

Tags: git

I wanted to move my branch to an earlier commit, so I ran:

```
git checkout 18C2 .
```

Where 18C2 is the identifier for that commit. As it happens, sometime after that commit I had renamed response.pm to Response.pm. The checkout works fine as far as the files are concerned - it removes Response.pm and adds response.pm

NOTE: I am on Windows. So Response.pm and response.pm would be considered the same file from Windows' standpoint. The value of config.ignoreCase is true, but Git did let me rename the file with git mv.

However, when I run git status, Response.pm is still there in a sense:

```
> git status
On branch return2
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Response.pm
```

I'm not really sure why it's there, but I tried to get rid of it with `git checkout -- Response.pm` as suggested. But once I do that and run git status again, I see the same message but with response.pm this time. Basically I can go back and forth.

What is going on here?

Comment: Missing information: are you on a case-folding operating system? (That is, if you name files `readme`, `Readme`, and `README`, is that *one* file, or three *different* files?) What is `core.ignoreCase` set to?

Comment: Sorry. I updated the question with this: NOTE: I am on Windows. So Response.pm and response.pm would be considered the same file from Windows' standpoint. The value of config.ignoreCase is true, but Git did let me rename the file with git mv.

Comment: OK - I haven't tried any of this on Windows (I avoid Windows) but I do have MacOS, which has the same case-folding behavior. In general Git has some trouble with these things, but when `config.ignoreCase` is `true` Git is *supposed* to do better. I'll have to poke around with it later, when I have more time, if no one else answers before then.

Comment: Incidentally, the issue is also apparent when running `git diff`. I forget exactly what I was diffing, but you see a problem either when a rename (with only case changed) has occurred between the two commits, or when it's gone back and forth between the two commits.

Comment: At this point I'm just going to chalk it up to "git can't properly handle cases like this" and leave it there since it isn't causing me significant problems, but of course I'll be curious if you come up with anything.

Comment: There is a conflict between the way your OS handles file names when only capitalization differs, and the way git handles them. I don't think this is just git's fault. Windows can be blamed, too.

Comment: You sure you don't have _both_ files in your tree at this commit?  What does `git ls-files --stage | grep -i response.pm` show from git bash?

Comment: @EdwardThomson It would be impossible to have both files in my directory since that isn't possible in Windows. However the output of the command you mentioned shows both Response.pm and response.pm. Strange!

Comment: No, you can't have them both in your _working directory_.  But git is case sensitive, so you _can_ have them both in your _commit_.  (And, it appears, you do.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow, you have both `response.pm` and `Response.pm` in your tree at that commit.  This can happen when somebody on a case sensitive filesystem decides to add both files, but it's most likely that somebody on a case *insensitive* filesystem has decided to turn off `core.ignorecase`.

(Aside: **never** turn off `code.ignorecase`.  It's not an configuration option that you can decide to opt in or opt out of.  It's how Git knows how to work with your filesystem.  It's stored in the configuration not so that you can change it, but because it needs to cache the information about how your filesystem works.  It determines this when the repository is created; rederiving it on every git command invocation would be prohibitively expensive.)

You should pick one of the files to keep.  Note that they may actually have different *contents*.  You can determine which you would like by running `git checkout -- response.pm` and `git checkout -- Response.pm`.  When you have the one that you want to keep in your working directory, remove them *both* from the index:

```
git rm --cached response.pm
git rm --cached Response.pm
```

Make sure that you have the filename that you want in your working directory:

```
rename response.pm Response.pm
```

(If necessary.)

And add it:

```
git add Response.pm
```

Comment: Thanks. For the record I had never turned off ignoreCase, yet somehow I still got this. Not sure how. Anyway hopefully this resolves this.

Comment: Didn't mean to throw blame your way - it could have been anybody on the team.  It also could have happened during a merge between a branch that had one case and a branch that had the other.  

Comment: The thing is, I'm the only person on the "team", it's a personal repo, so I'm quite confident ignoreCase was always on. I guess you're saying it's branch-specific, but I would have never meddled with it for any branch because I didn't even know it existed. There must be some other way this can happen.

Comment: I do interact with Enterprise GitHub at work in the sense that that's my remote, but I created all of my branches locally and pushed them.

Comment: I didn’t mean that the setting is branch specific, I meant that you could have the filename different in each branch (independent of the ignorecase setting).  A merge could then produce the tree that you described.  I just assumed that ignorecase was the culprit because that’s where I see this happening the most.